# Bash script variables and parameter passing

Tags: macos, bash, scripting, shell

I'm trying to pass a string variable to an application in a bash script:

```
    # launch app for translator to verify
    DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"

    langstr="'(English)'"
    case $language in
    "fr") 
        langstr="'(French)'";;
    esac

    echo $langstr
    #$DIR/../Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -AppleLanguages '(French)'
    $DIR/../Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -AppleLanguages $langstr
```

The echo reveals that `$langstr` is what I expect it to be: `'(French)'`.  The commented line with the hard coded language parameter works fine (app launches in French), but substituting that with the line with the `$langstr` variable launches the app in English which probably means that it ignored it some how.

What I probably need is to find myself a lesson on bash variable usage, but I was hoping to get a quick answer here in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the parameter using a variable like that, the single quotes are considered to be part of the parameter's value. So, your application gets literally the string `'(French)'`, while it probably expects just `(French)`. Change the variable assignment to `langstr="(French)"`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do  you need the cd command in a variable? Just do it as it is

```
langstr="(English)"
case $language in
"fr") 
    langstr="(French)";;
esac

echo $langstr
DIR=$(dirname "$0")
$DIR/../Debug/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp -AppleLanguages "$langstr"
```